# python argument on value

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a results_table as below:

```
               sum_sq         df           F            PR(>F)
    ABC         4.13          4.0        337.2           2.53
    Residual    4.45         110.0       NaN             NaN
```

What I am trying to do to print out 'test positive' only if PR(>F) is greater than 1. I tried the below:

```
if results_table.loc[[1],'PR(>F)'] > 1:
    print('test positive')
```

But I get the below error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"
```

Could someone please help me with how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually trying to access a *single* value then this

```
if results_table.loc['ABC', 'PR(>F)'] > 1:
    print('test positive')
```

or better this ([`.at[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is optimised for this kind of access)

```
if results_table.at['ABC', 'PR(>F)'] > 1:
    print('test positive')
```

should work.

The brackets here `.loc[[1], 'PR(>F)']` or here `.loc[['ABC'], 'PR(>F)']` make the result a series.

Answer (score 0):

With loc use should row/col names

```
if results_table.loc[['ABC'],'PR(>F)'] > 1:
    print('test positive')
```

Comment: this gives me the below error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().